# get string from right hand side

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a query in Oracle.

I want to get a string from the right hand side but the string length is dynamic.

Ex:

299123456789

I want to get 123456789

```
substr(PHONE_NUMBERS,-X,Y)
```

X is different for each record.

I tried this:

```
substr(PHONE_NUMBERS,-length(PHONE_NUMBERS),Y)
```

and it didn't work..

How can I write this query?

Comment: sorry, column name is PHONE_NUMBERS

Comment: Actually I solved the problem with Reverse function. I curios is there any function that retrieve data from right hand side?  For example : 9 characters from right side of string..

Answer (score 75):

If you want to list last 3 chars, simplest way is

```
 select substr('123456',-3) from dual;
```

Comment: What about select substr('12',-3) from dual; the result would be empty

Comment: @nokieng
To avoid such situation, I would pad the left side with some spaces and then trim it.

`select trim(substr('   ' || '12', -3)) from dual`

Answer (score 18):

```
SQL> select substr('123456',-1,6) from dual;

S
-
6

SQL> select substr('123456',-6,6) from dual;

SUBSTR
------
123456

SQL> select substr('123456',-7,6) from dual;

S
-
```

If you watch above statements, 3 query gives null value as -7 > length('123456').

So check the length of `CONT_PHONE_NUMBERS` and `PHONE_NUMBERS`

Hope this helps you

Comment: I dont know the length of PHONE_NUMBERS. Each record has different length.

Comment: @Jack, Bharat's answer will work regardless of the length of the data. A negative argument for the second parameter of SUBSTR counts from the end of the string.

Comment: @Jeffrey I know it, but length of the string is different for each record, so I have to use  length function or something like that for the negative argument

Comment: @Jack: Can you post your query and the output of that query

Comment: ok. I solved. Solution: substr(PHONE_NUMBERS,length(PHONE_NUMBERS)-9,9)

Comment: Shouldn't that be substr(PHONE_NUMBERS,length(PHONE_NUMBERS)-8,9)

Answer (score 10):

```
SQL> select substr('999123456789', greatest (-9, -length('999123456789')), 9) as value from dual;

VALUE
---------
123456789

SQL> select substr('12345', greatest (-9,  -length('12345')), 9) as value from dual;

VALUE
----
12345
```

The call to `greatest (-9, -length(string))` limits the starting offset either 9 characters left of the end or the beginning of the string.

Comment: As per Adam's answer, the greatest prevents the negative offset being longer than the string - i.e. substr('this string',-9) will give the 9 rightmost characters of the string BUT not if the string is SMALLER than 9 characters. The Greatest of (-9,-6) is -6. The greatest ensures it cannot offset longer than the length of the string.

Comment: Couldn't edit so a second comment.

This is the right answer. The greatest prevents the negative offset being longer than the string - i.e. substr('0123456789',-9) will give the 9 rightmost characters of the string. substr('0123456789',-12) gives NULL. The offset cannot be LONGER than the string. The GREATEST ensures this : GREATEST( -LENGTH('0123456789'),-12) is GREATEST(-10,-12) is -10. It ensures the offset is not longer than the string, which the first answer will not do. The first answer will work so long as string is always longer than X.

Comment: Jack - the greatest () of two negative numbers is the least negative of the two.  In the second of the two examples, greatest (-9, -5) evaluates to -5.

Answer (score 10):

I just found out that `regexp_substr()` is perfect for this purpose :)

My challenge is picking the right-hand 16 chars from a reference string which theoretically can be everything from 7ish to 250ish chars long. It annoys me that `substr( OurReference , -16 )` returns `null` when `length( OurReference ) < 16`. (On the other hand, it's kind of logical, too, that Oracle consequently returns `null` whenever a call to `substr()` goes beyond a string's boundaries.) **However, I can set a regular expression to recognise everything between 1 and 16 of any char right before the end of the string:**

```
regexp_substr( OurReference , '.{1,16}$' )
```

When it comes to performance issues regarding regular expressions, I can't say which of the `GREATER()` solution and this one performs best. **Anyone test this?** Generally I've experienced that regular expressions are quite fast if they're written neat and well (as this one).

Good luck! :)

Comment: Why is it logical to return null when substr() goes beyond the boudaries? What if I want it to return the strings with length less than my argument?

Answer (score 3):

```
substr(PHONE_NUMBERS, length(PHONE_NUMBERS) - 3, 4)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Add some english for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

the pattern maybe looks like this :

```
substr(STRING, ( length(STRING) - (TOTAL_GET_LENGTH - 1) ),TOTAL_GET_LENGTH)
```

in your case , it will like this :

```
substr('299123456789', (length('299123456789')-(9 - 1)),9)

substr('299123456789', (12-8),9)

substr('299123456789', 4,9)

the result ? of course '123456789'
```

the length is dynamic , voila :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTR('299123456789',DECODE(least(LENGTH('299123456789'),9),9,-9,LENGTH('299123456789')*-1)) value from dual
```

Gives 123456789

The same statement works even when the number is less than 9 digits:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('6789',DECODE(least(LENGTH('6789'),9),9,-9,LENGTH('6789')*-1)) value from dual
```

Gives 6789

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
substr('299123456',-6,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem. This worked for me:

```
 CASE WHEN length(sp.tele_phone_number) = 10 THEN
                   SUBSTR(sp.tele_phone_number,4)
```

Answer (score -1):

Below solution is perfect for this purpose:

```
select mod('299123456789',1000000000) from dual;
```